# Remove characters using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove the following characters from a string value using `xsl 1.0`

`*, /, \, #, %, !, @, $, (, ), &`

I have come up with the following:

```
translate(translate(translate(string(//xpath/@value),'.',''),'/',''),',','')
```

In the above approach, I would have to duplicate the same code many times (one time per character).

How can I achieve the same goal without duplicating the code?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You simply need `translate(//foo/@value, '*\%!@$&', '')` in pure XPath respectively inside of an XML document like an XSLT stylesheet you need to escape the ampersand `<xsl:value-of select="translate(//foo/@value, '*\%!@$&amp;', '')"/>`.

Answer (score 24):

**The `translate()` function accepts as its second and third argument two *strings* -- not just two characters**.

```
translate(., $string1, '')
```

produces a string which is the string value of the context (current) node in which any occurence of a character that is in `$string1` is deleted.

**Therefore you can use**:

```
translate(expressionSelectingNode, "/\#%!@$()&", "")
```

**to delete any of the characters contained in the second argument**.

Of course, if the `translate()` function is used within an XSLT stylesheet (or, generally within an XML document), some special characters, such as `<` and `&` must be escaped respectively as `&lt;` and `&amp;`.

**Using this is so powerful, that one can remove a set of *unknown* characters**:

Imagine that you want to remove from any string all characters that are not numeric. We don't know in advance what characters would be present in the string, therefore we cannot just enumerate them in the second argument of `translate()`. However we can still delete all these unknown charcters like that:

```
translate(., translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')
```

The inner `translate()` produces the string sans any digits.

The outer `translate()` deletes all this non-digit characters (found by the inner `translate()`) from the original string -- therefore what remains are only the digit characters.

Comment: This was quite helpful to me, but in the `translate(translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')` line, I think the outer translate is missing its first parameter, no?

Comment: @Beska, No, the outer `translate()` has as its 1st argument the result of the inner `translate()`, and as 2nd argument the empty string. So, the arguments are: 1. `translate(., '0123456789', '')`  and 2. `''`

Comment: But doesn't translate require three params?  (When I tried this code out as-is, it complained about that for me.  I had to add the path as a first param.)

Comment: @Beska You are right -- what is missing here is the 1st argument, which is the context node `.` -- so this must be: `translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')`   I already edited the answer. Thank you for noticing this!