# remove backspace from XML

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have to process a XML file which has some special characters in field values.
So can you please suggest a XSLT mapping code how to escape BACK SPACE (Unicode:0x8) from my data.

Input XML:

[image]

Note: The value for the `mart` field shows back space after the string 53.

Comment: Please don't post text like XML as images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153304/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/13089002/1531971 among others.